# tvOS - Best way to manage downloaded videos and images while app is running

Tags: xcode, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I read that there is no persistent local storage for tvOS. Any data stored or any downloaded data will get erased at any time.

Then what is the best way to keep track of images and videos downloaded while app is running? I'm planning to make an app that is basically a slideshow of images and videos. Images/Vidoes will be downloading in the background during the slideshow.

Number of images/videos could get large, so when I try to show video, the video might have been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no persistent local storage for apps on Apple TV. This means that every app developed for the new Apple TV must be able to store data in iCloud and retrieve it in a way that provides a great customer experience.

Only 1mb can be stored using NSUserDefaults.

I think your best bet is to use iCloud.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/

Comment: I want the slideshow to be 'smooth'. Let's say I want to show 10 videos. I will show the first video that gets downloaded and download other videos in background. Videos that finished downloading will be shown next. After showing 10 videos, I want to be in a loop, so I try to play the first video again. But my understanding is that the first video might not be available anymore. If the video is not available, the slideshow has to be 'paused' for redownload. I assume I have to keep checking if next videos are available and if not redownload it? Wondering if there is a good way of doing this.

Comment: You better use streaming then. Remember that the apple tv will **always** be connected to the internet. EDIT: You can pass an URL to the av player. You don't have to have the video as an asset

Answer (score 3):

My app has the same requirement, and I managed to solve it by creating my own persistence cache in .CachesDirectory. I store downloaded video and images, as well as the core data database file in this directly. You just need to make it sure that your application can deal with occasional "purge" by iOS, and handle it gracefully.

I am about to open source it in github, but the beta version is available at the following directory.

https://bitbucket.org/satoshinakajima/swipebeta

Open the sample project in your Xcode, and take a look at files in the "network" group, such as SwipeAssetManager.swift and SwipeConnection.swift, which are the persistent cache implementation. You can probably reuse them almost as-is.